# Proving limits with the definition of limit

Tags: limits, cauchy-sequences

I have the following task:

> Justify the following statements without using continuity of elementary functions (i.e. it has not yet
> been proved that $x_{\{n\}} \to a$, as $n \to \infty$ implies that $f(x_{\{n\}}) \to f(a)$, as $n \to \infty$):

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \sqrt[k]{a}=1, a > 0 $$
$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \sqrt[k]{k}=1$$
$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{k^\alpha}{b^k}=0, b > 1$$

I tried to use defenition of limit $|x_{n} - A| < \xi$, but I am not sure in this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $a>1$
$$a=[1+(\sqrt[n]{a}-1)]^n > n(\sqrt[n]{a}-1)$$
and we obtain $0<\sqrt[n]{a}-1<\frac{a}{n}<\varepsilon$, when $n>\frac{a}{\varepsilon}$.

For $0<a<1$ will be $b=\frac{1}{a}>1$ and we can use already obtained result, or directly $|\sqrt[k]{a}-1|=\left| \frac{1}{\sqrt[k]{b}} - 1 \right|<|\sqrt[k]{b}-1|$.

For second example works same approach.

For third, when $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$ is enough to consider $\frac{k}{b^k}$, for $b>1$:
$$\frac{k}{b^k}=\frac{k}{[1+(b-1)]^k}=\frac{k}{1+(b-1)k+\frac{k(k-1)}{2}(b-1)^2+\cdots +(b-1)^k}<\frac{2k}{k(k-1)(b-1)^2}=\\=\frac{2}{(k-1)(b-1)^2}$$

**Addition**.
Let's consider any $\varepsilon >0$.
$$\frac{2}{(k-1)(b-1)^2}< \varepsilon \Leftrightarrow \frac{2}{\varepsilon(b-1)^2}< (k-1)$$
Now if we choose $K=\left\lfloor \frac{2}{\varepsilon(b-1)^2} +1\right\rfloor+1 \in \mathbb{N}$, then for $k>K$ holds $\frac{k}{b^k}< \varepsilon$.

Comment: @nicomezi. If under "unwanted" you mean continuity forbidden by OP, then no. I mean only operation on fractions i.e. $a=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}}$ .

Comment: @nicomezi. What are you calling "continuity of the inverse operation"? We have theorem for limit of sequences ratio, which in each calculuse/math.analysis course/book is introduced before even concept of continuity. Or you speak about division as group operation and it's continuity as, for example, function $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$? It's even more late conception, then $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ continuity and when OP speaks about "without using continuity of elementary functions", then, I am sure, he doesn't mean division.  Well, for that case I added one inequality to answer.

Comment: @zkutch can you explain please, how you got $\frac{2}{(k-1)(b-1)^2}$? By Bernoulli’s inequality?

Comment: @Mouvre. Added details to answer - it's binomial theorem. Feel free, please, to ask more if/when it will be needed. And let me also ask from my side - do you mean in your question, not to using in answer well known theorem for algebraic operations for limits i.e. sum, subtraction, multiplication and division? I understand, that your "without using continuity of elementary functions" mean restriction on using, for example, root(power), exponential and so on elementary functions continuity.

Comment: @zkutch Thanks. We can use everything exept facts about elementary limits. Also, can you explain, please, why after decomposition a polynomial by binomial theorem, we can determine, that the fraction less, than $\frac{2k}{k(k-1)(b-1)^2}$? This is not obvious for me.

Comment: @Mouvre. All members in denominator are $\geqslant 0$, so through them away decrease denominator, so increase fraction: $0<a<b \Rightarrow \frac{1}{b} < \frac{1}{a}$. Ask any detail, please, which seems doubtful. For example, do you want case with $\alpha \notin \mathbb{N}$? And, sorry, as "facts about elementary limits" again leave room for ambiguity, let me ask exactly do you allow to use property $\frac{\lim x_n}{\lim y_n}=\lim \frac{x_n}{y_n}$ (assuming denominators $\ne 0$)? This is not fact about elementary functions, but algebraic operation for limits.

Comment: @zkutch Yes, I think, it possible to use fact about limits division, as it easily provable via limit definition and triangle inequality. So, we came to the $\frac{2k}{k(k-1)(b-1)^2}$, because we just took it as assumption that this fraction greater than initial? Could you please explain on this particular example? It must be possible to prove it in another way, for example using Bernoulli’s inequality, but I came to nothing, trying this approach. And in my task we have no restriction on $\alpha$, so $\alpha\notin\mathbb{N}$ is also considerable.

Comment: @Mouvre.  $\frac{k}{b^k} < \frac{2}{(k-1)(b-1)^2}$ is not assumption - we prove it. Then we use $A \cdot \frac{1}{k} \to 0, k \to \infty$, where $A$ is some constant - is this clear, or you prefer some elaboration?

Comment: @zkutch Elaboration will be very appreciated.

Comment: @Mouvre. Put addition in answer. Write, if something is unclear.

Comment: @nicomezi. Question is set by OP and he counts "possible to use fact about limits division" - find this in comments above. So he do not count this as elementary function and initial answer is acceptable for OP. I also do not consider algebraic operations among calculus, so called, elementary functions. But nevertheless there is also inequality, which gives case $0<a<1$ without theorems for division.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112751/discussion-between-mouvre-and-zkutch).

Comment: I have already upvoted your answer a few hours ago. You added details which were missing at the beginning regarding the OP's request so its fine.

Comment: Thanks, of course, for kind estimating, though my view on your remarks I wrote twice and have nothing to add.